# TeXworks won't detect my dictionaries

Tags: texworks

I followed the instructions on [this page](https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/wiki/SpellingDictionaries) to install spell checking dictionaries.

> If you have version 0.3 or later, you can use "Scripts -> Scripting TeXworks -> Show Scripts Folder" and navigate to the parent directory in the window that opens. (...) You should have a TeXworks resources directory in your "user profile" directory, typically C:\Documents and Settings\Your Name. This is automatically created the first time you run TeXworks, and some default resources are copied there. There should be a dictionaries subdirectory, but it is initially empty. Place the *.dic and *.aff files there, and then re-start TeXworks.

I let TeXworks open my scripts folder (which is *C:\Users\Pieter\TeXworks\scripts*), created a subdirectory called *dictionaries* and added the DIC/AFF files for *en_US*. After restarting TeXworks it still doesn't report any spell checking languages. What gives?

Comment: So you created the dictionaries folder within the scripts folder? That's wrong, the dictionaries folder should be in the *parent* folder of the scripts folder, e.g. C:\Users\Pieter\TeXworks\dictionaries.

Comment: D'oh. Thanks for pointing that out, Torbjørn. If you post your comment as an answer I can credit you for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *dictionaries* folder should not be placed within the *scripts* folder, but in the parent folder to this, i.e., the *scripts* and *dictionaries* folders should be on the same level. Hence, the path to the latter would be something like

```
C:\Users\Pieter\TeXworks\dictionaries
```

Answer (score 2):

On GNU/Linux, the dictionaries are searched for in `/usr/share/myspell/dicts`.

On some systems, the Hunspell dictionaries are put elsewhere (for instance in `/usr/share/hunspell/`).

In this case, you can do:

```
# cd /usr/share/myspell/dicts
# ln -s /usr/share/hunspell/en_US.aff
# ln -s /usr/share/hunspell/en_US.dic
```

Answer (score 0):

for MiKTeX 2.9 the installed dictionaries are in

```
...\MiKTeX 2.9\hunspell\dicts
```

But you can configure TeXworks to whatever you need.